A logical system in Grundlagen der Mathematik(vol.1, § 4])
In [1, § 4] a logical system (let us temporarily name it HB1) close to second-order logic(SOL) was introduced.
The main difference between HB1 and first-order logic(FOL) is that HB1 has formula variables with arguments similar to predicate variables(not presented in FOL). A rather complicated substitution rule for
formula variables with arguments was also introduced (p.89). Please look at an excerpt
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aQssQJt5nHJO01VektLL9lpJwzbMpbH7/view?usp=sharing
from the book[1] where formula variables with arguments were introduced. From this excerpt, it is clear that formula variables with arguments are actually second-order variables not presented in first-order logic.
Is there an accepted name for the logical system HB1?
More generally, is there a comprehensive list of formal logical systems used in mathematical logic?
Bibliography
[1] David Hilbert and Paul Bernays. Grundlagen der Mathematik= Foundations of mathematics,
Vol 1, Part B. College Publications, 2011. Translated from German, ed. Wirth, Claus-Peter and Siekmann, Jorg and Gabbay, Michael and Gabbay, Dov.

The treatise introduces predicate logic in § 4. It seems quite standard; in fact, the first German edition of 1934 was "the standard"

@MauroALLEGRANZA Do you think that formula variables with arguments are standard in FOL?

@MauroALLEGRANZA  https://brilliant.org/wiki/predicate-logic/ states that "predicate logic and FOL are synonyms: "Predicate logic, first-order logic or quantified logic is a formal language in which propositions are expressed in terms of predicates, variables and quantifiers. It is different from propositional logic which lacks quantifiers."

@MauroALLEGRANZA Because formula variables with arguments are actually predicate variables, I asked Google the following question:
Does predicate logic have predicate variables? The answer was:
AI Overview
No, in standard predicate logic (also called first-order logic), there are no "predicate variables" ....
See also https://www.bu.edu/linguistics/UG/course/lx502/_docs/lx502-predicate%20logic%201.pdf
You wrote: "Not exactly: predicate logic is more general".
You seem to have your definition of the term "predicate logic". What is your definition?

@MauroALLEGRANZA Wikipedia https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_logic states:
The term "predicate logic" has 2 meanings:

First-order logic (more often used); 2. Any logic(i.e. any formal logical system) that uses predicates.

I can't entirely agree with your first comment:
"The treatise introduces predicate logic in § 4. It seems quite standard; in fact, the first German edition of 1934 was "the standard""
Maybe you should write: "The treatise introduces a predicate logic in § 4."

Otherwise, in your statement, "predicate logic" means "first-order logic".
First-order logic is the standard, not the version of predicate logic in [1, § 4], because predicate variables are not present in FOL.

@MauroALLEGRANZA You can view or download the English translation of Grundlagen der Mathematik (Vol 1, part B) at https://drive.google.com/file/d/1x41Zj2RIx_mHAaNcwvEOU9H6IWy7gDjy/view?usp=sharing

The treatise introduces predicate logic in § 4: it is quite standard; in fact, the first German edition of 1934 was one of "the standards".
The authors have already dealt with propositional calculus § 3 and now they introduce predicate calculus (see e.g. Classical Logic). We have first-order predicate logic when only individual variables can be quantified, and High-Order Logic when also predicate variables can be quantified. See Second-Order Logic.
Starting with sentential calculus where the "atoms" are statements $A$ not further analyzed, with which we build compelx formulas using connectives : $A∨¬A$, in the predicate calculus we "split the atoms" into subject-predicate using predicate letters: $P,Q,…$ and individual variables: $x,y, …$ Thus instead of an atomic sentence $A$ ("Socrates is mortal") we have $A(x)$ ("x is mortal") then we generalize form unary predicates to multi-arguments ones $A(x,y)$ like e.g. $(x m\in y)$ and $x \lt y)$.
Then we can apply again connectives to them: $(x∈y)∨¬(x∈y)$ as well as quantifiers: $∀y∃x(x∈y)$
Page 89 deals with substitution. For individual variables, the machinery is simple; in modern terms: $A[x/y]$ means that from $A(x)$ we get $A(y)$ For predicates it is a little bit more thorny; the issue is that we can replace a generic predicate $A(x,y)$ with a compelx formulas, provided that the numeber of arguments match. Thus, if we have $\Phi(a,b,c)$, cannot us in place of $A(x,y)$, but we have to "identify" to argument-places in order to reduce it to a two argument places formula, like e.g. $\Phi(a,a,b)$.
What does it mean in practice? That we can instantiate the general formula $A(x,y)$ with both $(x < y)$ or $(x \in y)$ but not with (the formal counterpart of) "x is between y and z".
